# First aid: alternatives to hydrogen peroxide

Tags: gear, health, first-aid

###### ** This question may contain medically unsound advice. Be sure you have read the answers and comments before making any medical decisions **

---

Recently a friend broke her arm while mountain biking and the [bandages](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0271/1692/9068/products/CB.1.jpg?v=1579300289) I was carrying proved invaluable for stopping(slowing) the bleeding and getting her away from the mountain.

In the hospital they prescribed her TWO concurrent types of antibiotics to combat the jagged cut with inserted sand and offered her a tetanus jab.

I know washing the wound with H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> is optimal while alcohol and iodine are not. But all those three are liquids and thus weigh rather much. Also the procedure to use H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> is quite wasteful: "wash the wound without touching it".

Does there exist an alternative immediate treatment to open wounds that weighs less and is just as effective as washing with plenty of H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub>?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129660/discussion-on-question-by-vorac-first-aid-alternatives-to-hydrogen-peroxide).

Answer (score 33):

Water.

The American Red Cross Wilderness First Aid courses in 2021 recommend irrigating wounds with at least a liter of potable water, using an irrigation syringe.  If you don't have enough potable water, washing with non-potable water is acceptable and you should finish off with potable water.

The stronger antiseptic chemicals are indeed antiseptic, but they also can cause some damage to tissue with their antiseptic properties, and aren't typically used in sufficient quantities to thoroughly clean the wound.   Water is more effective than hydrogen peroxide, alcohol, iodine, etc. for cleaning and irrigation.  With larger quantities of water, you can flush more dirt out of the wound, reducing the chance of septic contamination, rather than trying to overwhelm it with antiseptic.

Comment: As reasonable as your answer is, it doesn't address the "lightweight" portion of my question. To be truly complete, an answer need to address why 5g of anibiotic powder is just as good as 1kg of water.

Comment: 1kg of water is something that you might already be carrying for drinking, so it could be a zero weight penalty option.

As for a comparison with 5g of antibiotic powder, I didn't see that in your question.  I thought the question was about cleaning.   Covering a dirty wound with antibiotics is different treatment than cleaning.  If you cover a dirty wound with 5g of antibiotic powder, a good health care provider will probably debride and irrigate the wound, cleansing it of any field-applied antibiotic powder or other debris before closing it up and dressing it.

Comment: @Vorac the lightweight alternative to 1kg of water is....... less water. There isn't really an ultralight equivalent alternative. There doesn't exist something super light weight that will magically fix a wound.

Comment: @Vorac anything lighter than water would reasonably be used in addition to water, not in place of it.  Removing debris is both more important than applying medication and a prerequisite for it; the treatments you can buy don't remove debris.  Another way to look at it is that you can disinfect the outside of a lump of dirt, but not the side touching the damaged flesh (to a good approximation). Further the presence of even perfectly clean grit is a bad thing

Comment: One thing that may strike the balance is a saline spray (often used for sinus irrigation). Each can of saline is lighter weight than a comparable volume of water and the jet is powered by a propellant, helping to debride any dirt. The solutions are also isotonic, which will help mitigate the burning you would get from drinking water.

Answer (score 16):

When someone is so badly injured that they need immediate professional medical treatment, and you are able to get them that treatment within a day, then wound disinfection isn't a priority. Infections take days to set in, and modern antibiotics administered at the hospital can prevent that from happening.

According to several first aid courses I did, trying to clean life-threatening wounds as a first aid measure can do more harm than good. You will wash away the blood which already started clotting the arteries. And trying to remove debris can cause further injury or open up blocked arteries. So by cleaning a wound you cause more blood loss. So focus on stopping the bleeding and getting an ambulance.

However, for smaller cuts and bruises which don't warrant a visit to a doctor, there is spray-on wound disinfectant which weights very little and can be applied in a contactless manner. You can buy it at any well-stocked pharmacy. Rinse away the debris with water, dry the wound with tissue paper and then spray the disinfectant onto the wound.

Regarding tetanus vaccination: Anyone who regularly engages in outdoor activities should take care to keep their tetanus shots up-to-date anyway. It's a vaccination which is easy to obtain and with very little risk of side-effects. Getting a tetanus booster when showing an injury to a doctor is usually standard procedure, just to be sure.

Comment: Part of the reason behind the tetanus booster is that after a full course of vaccination in childhood, there's good protection for life, but not necessarily complete protection. Anyway people don't always know what vaccines they've had.  A "tetanus shot" after an injury may also not be the vaccine but [immunoglobulin](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/tetanus/) (or both).

Comment: As for wound cleaning, advice varies.  First aid at work course tend to assume help is near, and cleaning not advised.  Wilderness first aid course are more likely to support prompt cleaning, subject to the priority of keeping the red stuff in. Of course the type of contamination is likely to be different. Outdoor activities not too far from hospitals fall somewhere in between, but if self-extraction is reasonable, a bit more cleaning and dressing   might be worthwhile than in an office

Comment: In UK it is [no longer considered necessary](https://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=194541) to have a 10-yearly tetanus booster, but 30-years. In UK I was refused when I last appplied for one, and have not bothered since. But of course, it might not be known whether someone has been immunised.

Comment: My wilderness first responder courses certainly included flushing open wounds with water to remove debris. This was presuming that the bleed itself was not immediately life threatening. Fully agree with @ChrisH that back country and front country first aid are two different things.

Comment: @JonCuster I've only done outdoor first aid, assuming no more than about a day's walk from help or a few hours from a signal (though taught by a wilderness/expedition medic).  Flushing with water, as you say, was the first call, ideally using the casualty's own bottle.  Now, when leading rides etc., I tend to keep a clean 2nd bottle of water, decanting from it if needed for drinking (also handy for dehydration).  Sterile saline is another useful option - I carry a couple of vials for rinsing eyes, but the narrow stream you get from them should be handy in some cases.

Comment: ... I haven't tested the latter though - last time I had to deal with some rather deep road rash it was on me, and I used my water bottle.  I was riding solo,  on the edge of a city, but chose to carry on once I got dressings to stay put.  That was a year ago and the scars have nearly gone. If treating someone else I probably would have advised them to get it looked at professionally.

Comment: @WeatherVane according to my NHS link, even that isn't usually given.  I seem to recall an adult top-up when getting some travel jabs in my 20s.  That may have been uncertainty, or may have been before advice changed (it was a while ago)=.  But the risk/return/treatment balance isn't drawn in quite the same place in all countries - in particular if treatment is expensive, employment protections weak, and vaccination profitable, it may stay recommended just in case.

Comment: @ChrisH - bike bottles are nearly ideal to get a steady stream. One suggestion at the courses was to get a ~1 pint soft squeeze bottle for your back country first aid kit - it squishes down pretty small. But just dumping a liter bottle on would work too - you want to get any loose foreign material out before bandaging up. Full cleaning waits for the professionals at the hospital. One of those tradeoffs of being in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: @JonCuster absolutely agreed on bike bottles.  Another trick I was shown was stabbing a hole in the cap of a typical 0.5l disposable bottle (which are very common in countries without safe  water) using the reamer of a penknife.  Generally I hike with bike bottles; a Nalgene or classic Sigg would be less effective - all your water coming out at once in a wide slow stream.

Comment: In regards to the spray on antibiotics, in a wilderness setting it is often recommended AGAINST in WFR/WFA courses. The reason being moisture. In an inherently dirty wilderness environment the topical antibiotic spray/cream has little added benefit while the moisture from the topical antibiotics can actually aid in bacterial growth. If you can't keep the wound clean (which in a wilderness context is somewhat a given) you are better off keeping it dry by not having the antibiotic. Leave the spray at home for minor urban cuts and scrapes. That is what it is designed for.

Comment: Regarding "So by cleaning a wound you cause more blood loss. So focus on stopping the bleeding and getting an ambulance." Except in rare and severe cases of high quantities of blood loss cleaning should take priority in a wilderness setting.

Comment: Good point @noah on the moisture (though wilderness can be very dry).  I wonder about the use of things like dry spray antiseptics on areas that are very hard to keep dressed  - the first time I had such stuff applied I'd badly grazed my hands push-starting a car. When it went, it really went, and so did I - downwards.  Palms are hard to protect with dressings, but a bad graze is far from a reason to call for evacuation.  Similar injuries can occur in biking, though gloves help a lot. Very much an edge case I admit

Comment: I've always heard antiseptics being recommended against for wilderness contexts. The 99.9% of bacteria includes the "good" stuff, and so in a wilderness context for scrapes like that it will potentially do more harm than good. Antiseptics really do kill everything

Answer (score 7):

Having perused my well read copy of NOLS Wilderness Medicine (available e.g. [through NOLS](https://store.nols.edu/products/nols-wilderness-medicine-6th-edition)), there is no mention of hydrogen peroxide use at all. The only two things mentioned for wound cleaning are (1) water, and (2) water with [povidone-iodine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Povidone-iodine). Use of a syringe to irrigate the wound is strongly suggested. If you have limited clean water, rinse with untreated water first, then finish with the clean (filtered, iodine, ...) water last. Going with the povidone-iodine solution, you need to rinse out the wound after the povidone-iodine before bandaging.

Personal take, based on the training, is that I would use the povidone-iodine solution for abrasions, a large area of damaged skin, where the exposed surface area makes infections more likely. For a clean deep cut, I would rinse with water and bandage it, counting on the limited wound area at the surface to keep the infection possibility lower. In the whole wide grey area in between those, well, you get to choose at the time based on the wound, the person, your party size, distance to a trail head, communication options, etc.

If the bleeding is potentially life threatening (arterial for example), then immediate pressure and bandaging, with rapid evacuation, are the way to go.